# Install SDL2 in VSCode and the compiler can't find the SDL.h

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, sdl-2, mingw32

I'm going to start doing a game project but when I'm trying to install SDL2 in VSCode. However, when I compile main.cpp there's a problem:
fatal error: SDL2/SDL.h: No such file or directory

I tried to follow the instruction on Youtube but this error keep happening.
I put the "SDL2.dll" to the same directory of the main.cpp file
This my "Makefile" file:

```
all:
    g++ -I src/include -L src/lib -o main main.cpp -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2
```

My c_cpp_properties.json:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "${workspaceFolder}/src/include"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/g++.exe",
            "cStandard": "gnu17",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++23",
            "intelliSenseMode": "windows-gcc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

All of this file are in the same directory as main.cpp

Comment: Don't manage SDL2 manually. Download it as a package from MSYS2 (`pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-SDL2`), then run `pkg-config --libs --cflags` to know what compiler flags to use.

Comment: Since you are using msys2 you can install SDL2 using pacman and that would put SDL2 in the system location removing the need to specify the include or link directories. You will still need to link to libraries.

Comment: @drescherjm how to link to libraries

Answer (score 1):

```
fatal error: <some_header_file.h>: No such file or directory
```

Is caused when the compiler cant find the header file specified by an `#include` statement in your code. In this case it must be because there *is no* SDL2/SDL.h file in your include path.

To link with a library in c++ you have to both tell the linker where to find an already compiled library file (on windows this is either a .dll or a .lib file), *and* you have to tell the compiler where to find the location of the libraries header files, for compiling with your own code.

This is because the compiler needs the definitions contained in the SDL header files to ensure your own code gets compiled correctly in such a way that the linker can actually link it with the compiled library later.

According to your question all you did was

> I put the "SDL2.dll" to the same directory of the main.cpp

This makes the linker able to find the library, however you also have to make the compiler able to find the SDL header files.

To do this you have to either copy over the include directory of SDL into your own include path (in this case it seems to be in src/include/) *or* tell the compiler where to find it, which you can do with the -I flag